# distribute iPhone applications built using "App Store" provisioning profile

Tags: iphone, ios4, app-store, xcode4.2

Is it possible to distribute iPhone applications built using "App Store" provisioning profile ? (Without submitting to App Store)

I know I can run the application by creating Ad-Hoc profile and linking device IDs. I want to run the App, but I want to run the app without adding any device IDs to developer portal or in devices which are not added to the portal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible. There are 3 ways to distribute iOS applications:

- via the App Store.
- by building to device (does require the device's id to be added to the provisioning profile).
- over the air (Ad Hoc) which does require you to add every device's id to the provisioning profile.

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible without jailbreaking. You have to use a distribution profile with device id's.